# New 14.04 LTS install fails to boot with purple screen

Tags: 14.04, graphics

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and it got to the prompt which said it had finished installing and needed to be restarted. When booting it shows a purple screen then the monitor switches off after with no video response. I can boot using recovery mode, so I think it might be graphics card related.

Is it possible to edit the settings to make the normal boot use default video drivers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section "Black/purple screen after you boot Ubuntu for the first time" from [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) helped. Installed NVIDIA drivers and now working.